# Drupal permissions not showing for custom content type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have a custom content type in Drupal which was created using CCK.

The create/edit permissions for this type are not showing up in the node module permissions, although other cck types are.

This content type is also bound to a module, but this module doesn't have any admin screens, all node creation is done through the standard cck interface.

any ideas?

I have tried rebuilding the permissions cache

Comment: what do you mean that the content type is bound to a module? did you create the content type or did the module? What is the module?

Comment: The content type was created through the admin UI, and then a module was created with the same name. It works fine, with the exception of the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was returning the name of the module itself in the hook_node_info array.
This needed to return "node" to ensure that permission hooks fired on the module.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a hook_perm to your module to define the permission manually. If it shows up then one might assume the module is overloading the permission.

Otherwise, perhaps try clearing your caches.